# setContent() for finishing an Activity not working on API 16

Tags: android, android-intent, onactivityresult

I am building an app where I need to select pictures from gallery or take new one via the camera. I built three activities: one activity that shows selected/taken pictures, one to select pictures from memory as a gallery, and one to take new pictures with the camera. What I do is: when the user click a button to get more pictures, I open an intent chooser like this:

```
Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Constants.INTENT_GALLERY);
Intent cameraIntent  = new Intent(Constants.INTENT_PHOTO_CAPTURE);

Intent chooserIntent 
            = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, getString(R.string.title_photo_chooser));
chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Intent[] { cameraIntent });

startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, Constants.SUCCESS);
```

Then the gallery and the camera activity finish like so:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();

intent.putStringArrayListExtra(Constants.INTENT_KEY_PHOTO, selected);

setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

And finally, the first activity, the viewer, gets the results like this:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        if( requestCode == Constants.SUCCESS ) {
            [...]
        }
    }
}
```

This has been proven successful on my cellphone with API 22. Unfortunately, when running on my tablet with API 16, in `onActivityResult()`, `resultCode` is never `RESULT_OK`, and `intent` is always *null*. I have seen many solutions like calling `getParent().setResult()`, but nothing seems to work.

Any tip would be useful. Thanks.

**EDIT**

I have analysed with a debugger the content of my activity in both version. Those states are the state of my `Gallery` activity just before the call to `finish()`. On API 22, I have this:

```
mParent = null
mResultCode = -1
mResultData = {Intent@5081} "Intent { (has extras) }"
    mAction = null
    mCategories = null
    mClipData = null
    mComponent = null
    mContentUserHint = -2
    mData = null
    mExtras = {Bundle@5134} "Bundle[{photo=[/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/....jpg, ...]}]"
    mFlags = 0
    mLaunchParams = {DualScreenLaunchParams@5135} "DualScreenLaunchParams { mScreen=UNKNOWN mFlags=0 }"
    mMultiWindowStyle = null
    mPackage = null
    mSelector = null
    mSourceBounds = null
    mType = null
    mWindowMode = 0
    mWindowPosition = null
    mWindowScale = 0.0
    shadow$_klass_ = {Class@1261} "class android.content.Intent"
    shadow$_monitor_ = -1875875432
```

On API 16, I have this:

```
mParent = null
mResultCode = -1
mResultData = {Intent@830041848224} "Intent { (has extras) }"
    mAction = null
    mCategories = null
    mClipData = null
    mComponent = null
    mData = null
    mExtras = {Bundle@830042231640} "Bundle[{photo=[/storage/sdcard0/Pictures/....jpeg, ...]}]"
    mType = null
    mPackage = null
    mSelector = null
    mSourceBounds = null
    mFlags = 0
```

There are differences but it seems `setContent()` did its job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got to the problem. The key was in the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle)) for `startActivityForResult`. It states:

> For example, if the activity you are launching uses the singleTask launch mode, it will not run in your task and thus you will immediately receive a cancel result.

I was indeed using `singleTask` as a launch mode. I switched to `singleTop` and it worked. I am studying launch modes to have everything working out.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure `setResult` is not being called before `finish()`

Comment: Well, as you can see above, `setResult()` is indeed called _before_ `finish()`. But, that would not make sense to call it _after_, no? Furthermore, in every answer I came across, it is always called _before_.